# Dart: how do I get first day of week for current locale?

Tags: dart

It can be done in Java by

```
com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance(Locale alocale).getFirstDayOfWeek()
```

Is there an equivalent way to get it in Dart?

Answer (score 9):

This thing worked for me

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();             
_firstDayOfTheweek = today.subtract(new Duration(days: today.weekday));
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind that this method will always consider Sunday the first day of the week, even in locales that should have have Saturday or Monday as the first day of the week. This is because the weekday value in Dart is 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday) see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html

Comment: @LeonLucardie "always consider Sunday the first day of the week"? so which is it - Monday or Sunday?

Comment: also 'subtract' ignores daylight saving time, so It will not return the correct day every time.

Answer (score 9):

With Flutter you can use just:

`MaterialLocalizations.of(context).firstDayOfWeekIndex;`

Answer (score 7):

Just found it:

https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/date_symbol_data_local.dart

Search for "FIRSTDAYOFWEEK" and it's not hard to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Google for "Dart: how do I get first day of week for current locale?" - here, I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 3):

To get first day of week, and last day of week:

```
 print("today is day: ${DateTime.now().weekday}");
print(
    "monday is day: ${DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: DateTime.now().weekday - 1))}");
print(
    "sunday is day: ${DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: DateTime.now().weekday - 1))}");
```

Comment: This is good stuff, though note that in the final example, the next Sunday after today, should be: `DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7 - DateTime.now().weekday))`

Answer (score 3):

After a long long long search, I found `jiffy` that solves my problem. You can use it with `Intl` and get what you want.

Just initialize it in your main.dart

```
void main() async {
  Intl.defaultLocale = Intl.systemLocale;   // Define the default locale as System Locale
  await Jiffy.locale(Intl.defaultLocale);   // Define Jiffy locale
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And then, you can use the `Jiffy` function to get start and end of week

```
print(Jiffy(date).startOf(Units.WEEK)); 
print(Jiffy(date).endOf(Units.WEEK));
```

Ref: https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to make it work. It would be nice Bob, if you could share your solution.

Here is mine for use in Flutter:

```
GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate
        .load(locale)
        .then((MaterialLocalizations materialLocalizations)
    {
        print("${materialLocalizations.firstDayOfWeekIndex}");
    });
```